# How to move (sort) the band in XtraReport?

Tags: devexpress, xtrareport

I am using DevExpress 12.2.7
Is there anyway to change the order of bands in XtraReport
I want to move the PageFooter to before of ReportFooter, but the up-down arrows seem to be disabled. I can't drag and drop the bands too.
[image]

Comment: I have never come across the ability to move the PageFooter above the ReportFooter, but to me this is because it makes sence for the PageFooter to be below the ReportFooter, why would you need to change there order?

Comment: I want to use page footer as summary of table content in each page, and report footer will appear in the last page (after that page "page footer")